# Android: how to execute method in Activity only if phone has been rebooted?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, reboot

I have the following problem: I have an Activity that is executed several times when the phone is switched on.

There is one particular method of the Activity that I have to call only ONCE and ONLY AFTER A REBOOT. Unfortunately I cannot listen to the BOOT_COMPLETED intent because the application is a Launcher.

**I was thinking about using sharedpreferences**, using a Boolean flag "first start".

But as far as I know `SharedPreferences` are persisted after reboot.

So I am stuck.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: still BOOT_COMPLETED is the only solution. You can register another broadcast receiver to receive that intent

Comment: @blackbelt thanks, please I have edited the question, actully I cannot do that because the application itself is a Launcher... Thanks anyway

Comment: Even if your application is a "Launcher" you still can and need to use BOOT_COMPLETED. Create a BroadcastReceiver. What is the problem?

Comment: @EvZ thanks. Please how can a launcher listen to BOOT_COMPLETED even before the launcher itself starts?

Comment: I think that you missing something, check more about intents in Android and BOOT_COMPLETED.